# javascript: putting getElementsByName in a function is it possible?

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to put the `getElementsByName()` to a function so I won't keep doing it all over again in any tag selector name?

Expected:

```
getName(name, onclick, iclickit, id, idname);

var elems = document.getElementsByName('name');

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].setAttribute('onclick', afunction);
    elems[i].setAttribute('id', 'testid');
}
```

Is it possible to put many `setAttributes()` when calling a function rather than keep putting that in every name selector?

Comment: Absolutely, JavaScript is a functional programming language I'll show you what the means.

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question at a time.  Also, it would be very easy to try these things out or to look for documentation online.  How much research did you do before asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is a functional programming language which means that you can compose many functions into what are called "higher order functions".

Here is an example

```js
    function aFunction(ev){
        ev.target.style.backgroundColor="red";
    }

    function getName(name, event, id){
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[name="'+ name + '"]');
        elems.forEach(function(elem){
            elem.addEventListener(event, aFunction);
            elem.id = id
        })
    }
    
    getName('random', 'click', 'thing');
```

```css
[name="random"]{
    background:blue;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div name="random"></div> 
<div name="random"></div>
```

I'm actually passing a function to forEach, and then I'm taking the output from each iteration and adding a listener that has a function passed into it.

Comment: im trying not to use queryselectorall for old browsers thats why im trying to use getelementsbyname.

Comment: Understood. I've personally never used getElementsByName so I wasn't sure if it was pseudocode or real code.

Comment: almost perfect for me but sadly i cant use it on old browser like the foreach :(

Comment: so use a for loop.

Comment: You're seriously still trying to support IE 7 in 2017?!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to put the getElementsByName to a function so I won't
>   keep doing it all over again in any tag selector name?

Yes,

```
function bindEventHandlerByTagName( tagName, evenHandler )
{
   Array.prototype.slice.call( document.getElementsByName( tagName ) ).forEach( function( element ){
      element.addEventListener( 'click', evenHandler );
   });    
}
```

To use this

```
bindEventHandlerByTagName( "span", function(){ console.log( "span clicked" ); } );
```

Comment: can you please provide an example using it? how about setting an attribute of id and etc.?

Comment: @E.Grey id of an element should be unique in a page, so keep it outside.